# tkinter changing input to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can I take an input in Tkinter and change it to int when appending to list. Instead of ['2015'] i want it to be [2015]

Also it's overwriting the list and not appending

Here's my code

```
from tkinter import *

def appendvalues():
    x = entry.get()
    lst = []
    lst.append(x)
    lst = [int(i) for i in lst]
    print(lst)

    

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

b1 = Button(root, text='submit', command=appendvalues)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're explicitly creating a new list in the function, and it _is_ appending, only it's appending to an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `int()` and append to the list.

```
from tkinter import *

lst = list()
def appendvalues():
    x = entry.get()
    lst.append(int(x))
    print(lst)

    

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

b1 = Button(root, text='submit', command=appendvalues)
b1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```